# Unable To Get Interval With Fluent Nhibernate In Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Column in Oracle DB as:

```
INTERVAL DAY (0) TO SECOND (6)
```

My Model:

```
public class IntervalTest
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan IntervalField { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent ModelMap:

```
public class IntervalTestMap : ClassMap<IntervalTest>
{
    public IntervalTestMap()
    {
        Table("INTERVALTESTTWO");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.IntervalField, "IFTest");
    }
}
```

When I run

```
criteria.List<T>();
```

I get the following Exception:

> {"could not execute query\r\n[ SELECT this_.Id as Id2_0_, this_.IFTest as IFTest2_0_ FROM INTERVALTESTTWO this_ ]\r\n[SQL: SELECT this_.Id as Id2_0_, this_.IFTest as IFTest2_0_ FROM INTERVALTESTTWO this_]"}

With an InnerException Of:

> {"ORA-00904: \"THIS_\".\"IFTEST\": invalid identifier"}

NHibernate works for all of my other models, only ones with an interval field do I get this exception. I've tried changing the column names in case that is an issue to no avail.

Thanks in advance if anyone has managed to get interval type working in Fluent NHibernate with Oracle DB and can help me.

***EDIT***

Solved; Adding

```
.Type<NHibernate.Type.TimeAsTimeSpanType>();
```

To the mapping made it work. Thanks To Radmin (answer below)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure about Oracle... but, As the documenation says:

**[5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)**

The C# TimeSpan is by default mapped to **`DbType.Int64`**. And this is not what we want.

Solution: **TimeAsTimeSpanType**

We can use this fluent mapping:

```
Map(c => c.IntervalField, "IFTest")
   .Type<NHibernate.Type.TimeAsTimeSpanType>();
```

See: [TimeAsTimeSpanType.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Type/TimeAsTimeSpanType.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps a <see cref="System.TimeSpan" /> Property to an 
/// <see cref="DbType.Time" /> column
/// This is an extra way to map a <see cref="DbType.Time"/>. You already have 
/// <see cref="TimeType"/>
/// but mapping against a <see cref="DateTime"/>.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class TimeAsTimeSpanType : PrimitiveType, IVersionType
```

See more about it also here: [Working with Time Type in Fluent Nhibernate generates exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'NHibernate.Type.TimeType"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26251926/1679310)

Also, I would suggest to try to escape the column name. In SQL Server is working "[ColumnName]". I guess in general, including Oracle, this is working

```
Map(x => x.IntervalField, "`IFTest`");
```

Comment: Still getting the same error I'm afraid! The Column Type is 'Interval Day To Second'. The error normally is due to invalid column name (unlike the casting issue from the linked post) which I've checked multiple times :(

Comment: Then I would suggest to escape the column name with special char. I updated my answer

Comment: Tried "'IFTEST'" & got: {"ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"}    When I tried "IFTEST'" got {"ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated"}. :/ Surely this indicates the column is right in the first place and oracle is throwing vague error?

Comment: Sir... wish to help more. Could you change the column name? At least to test if the Column Name is the issue? Could you try? And ... have you used the right sign to escape it?

Comment: Just used the correct escape sign (`) not (') and am getting the original error :/ I've tried changing the column name before I'll try again now

Comment: You Sir Are My New Best Friend! Turns out in my Haste, I'd changed the Column Name Earlier today and not updated my code. The .Type<NHibernate.Type.TimeAsTimeSpanType>(); seemed to make it work. Thanks for your help I've been googling for two straight days!

Comment: Great to see that sir! Because NHibernate is amazing tool;) Good luck ;)